# Une traduction pour « the pasting lemma / het plaklemma »

Tags: anglais, terminologie, mathématiques, néerlandais

Je cherche une traduction pour un lemme mathématique que je n’ai pas pu trouver en changeant de langue sur Wikipédia, car ce site ne donne pas assez de renseignements français. 
Il s’agit d’un moyen utile pour montrer qu’une fonction décrite sur une espace topologique est continue. Le lemme dit ceci :

> Soit X un espace topologique, union de deux sous-espaces
>   ouverts, disons *A* et *B*. Soit *f* une fonction continue sur *A* et
>   *g* une fonction continue sur *B*. Si les fonctions sont égales en tout point commun à *A* et *B*, alors l’énoncé suivant est vrai : La
>   fonction qui envoie tout *a* dans *A* vers *f(a)*, et tout *b* dans *B*
>   vers *f(b)* est continue.

Aussi bien pour l’anglais que pour le néerlandais, le nom de ce lemme comprend un composant de « coller ». Je dirais que la traduction française la contient aussi, mais je ne sais pas quels terminaisons je dois ajouter, et je ne sais pas si je dois écrire « re- » avant ce mot. Quelle peut bien être la traduction française ?

D’ailleurs, voici un lien vers la page [*Pasting lemma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) sur Wikipédia pour ceux qui voudraient le lire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On parle de "recoller" les fonctions, et on pourrait donc dire "lemme de recollement".

Plus précisément, les usages peuvent différer. Quand on m'a enseigné ce lemme, c'était sans lui donner de nom. De plus, si on ne précise pas ce qui est recollé, "Lemme de recollement" peut être utilisé pour autre chose. Reste que pour parler de cette opération sur les fonctions on n'utilise pas autre chose que "recollement". Si on veut donner un nom à ce résultat, ce sera bien "lemme de recollement". (Les deux premiers résultats de google sont http://www.latp.univ-mrs.fr/~paoluzzi/programmeta.pdf et http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~labessie/cours_top-geo.pdf, qui énoncent le résultat avec des fermés, mais l'opération est la même ; je n'ai jamais rencontré d'autre terminologie dans un cours ou un livre de topologie.)

Comment: La difficulté dans le cas présent est que le terme à trouver est celui qui est employé et reconnu dans la profession, et pas tout autre terme qui pourrait convenir.

Comment: @Edouard Si on cherche "lemme de recollement" sur google en français, on tombe sur des cours de topologie donnés dans plusieurs universités, et le lemme désigné correspond bien à la question posée.

Comment: Alors n’emploie pas le conditionnel et propose des sources. Personnellement, avec Google, je ne trouve pas grand chose pour « lemme de recollement » (une définition qui correspond, deux cas particuliers). En topologie, le recollement est semble-t-il plutôt [la notion](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recollement_(topologie)) qui se traduit par [Adjunction Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_space).

Answer (score 2):

J'entends encore mon prof parler (informellement) du recollement des cartes pour expliquer la définition des variétés différentiables par atlas.

L'article "Variété (géométrie)" de Wikipédia parle du "recollement de variétés" et renvoie à un article sur le sujet, qui a été défini mais pas encore rédigé.

Je parlerais du lemme du "recollement de deux fonctions continues", recollement sur une partie commune.